# Groovy script to increment the value of (asumend Text Field) custom field

Tags: groovy, jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

**Problem statement**: I want to set the custom script post-function to increment the custom field's (text field) by +1 on a specific workflow transition, for example, when the transition is fired from the status fixed - increment the Program,Label, and External field's by +1.

**Method**:  (Custom script post function)

**Field created**: Scripted field (Program, Lable & External) - Text Field

**Version**: Jira 8.20.6

Groovy Script i am using is throwing an error:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.customfields.CustomFieldType
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.DefaultIssueChangeHolder
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.IssueChangeHolder
 
ComponentManager componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = componentManager.getCustomFieldManager()
CustomField cf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_11727")
Double val = (issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf) as Double)
if ( val == null) 
 val = 1
else
 val = val + 1
IssueChangeHolder changeHolder = new DefaultIssueChangeHolder();
cf.updateValue(null, issue, new ModifiedValue(issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf),val), changeHolder)
```

Error is geting from Script Runner Console is "*unable to resolve class ComponentManager*"

Comment: Have you tried adding `import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager`

Comment: ComponentManager has been deprecated since JIRA 7.11, which is the reason that you cannot resolve this class any longer.  [Unable to Resolve](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/unable-to-resolve-class-com-atlassian-jira-ComponentManager/qaq-p/1054443)

Answer (score 0):

ComponentManager is deprecated as commented by [Manu Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7334927/manu-mishra)

replace this :

```
ComponentManager componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance()
CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = componentManager.getCustomFieldManager()
```

with this:

```
CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
```

and replace the import statement:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentAccessor
```

to:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
```